# Why would I get "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory" when viewing a Sinatra form?

Tags: ruby, forms, error-handling, terminal, sinatra

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra/

Got stuck in "We’ll also make use of a “**view file**”, which allows us to split the markup for a view into a separate file. "

I have my basics.rb file running fine.

**And My files are stored as follows:**

```
Desktop/RubyForm/basics.rb
Desktop/RubyForm/view/form.erb
```

However, now when i go to  `http://localhost:9393/form` , I am greeted with:

```
Errno::EIO at /form 
Input/output error - <STDERR> file: lint.rb location: write line: 398
sinatra.error   
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - 
  /Users/HelenasMac/Desktop/views/form.erb
```

**UPDATE! :** 
 Got the form to work right after running ruby basics.rb and going to `http://localhost:4567/form` .
However, after I run "shotgun basics.rb" , I have to go to
`http://localhost:9393/form`, and that's when the form doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong? Disclaimer: mega beginner to ruby and using the terminal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your **current working directory** is `Desktop/RubyForm` when you run `basics.rb`? I.e. when you go into the terminal you have to type: `cd Desktop/RubyForm` to change your working directory, then `ruby basics.rb` to start the server.

Comment: Are you running `shotgun` also in `Desktop/RubyForm`? I just tried the tutorial on my Linux box and it works as expected on this machine. You sure you don't have a file named `basics.rb` directly in `Desktop` too, and you're running that one by mistake?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  Part of it was that i did have extra basics.rb files laying around, part of it was that something was getting tweaky because i restarted my computer and then it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot get `shotgun` to work then the [new recommended way to reload Sinatra seems to be `rerun`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading).

To use it:

```
> gem install rerun
> cd /Users/HelenasMac/Desktop/RubyForm
> rerun ruby basics.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicity Set a Views Directory

Unless you're using inline template for your views with `enable :inline_templates`, you may need to explicitly define a template directory if the default values aren't working for you. The docs [describe how to set your views directory](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) as follows:

> :views - view template directory
>
> A string specifying the directory where view templates are located. By default, this is assumed to be a directory named “views” within the application’s root directory (see the :root setting). The best way to specify an alternative directory name within the root of the application is to use a deferred value that references the :root setting:
>
> set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }

You may also need to explicitly set **:root**, and make sure that both **:root** and **:views** make sense from your current working directory.

Comment: Sinatra should use the `views` folder by default for templates. The prerequisite is that the cwd of the running process is the root of the application. In this instance it seems she started the app from `Desktop`, not from `Desktop/RubyForm`.

Comment: @Casper By default it does, but it constructs `:root` from `File.dirname(__FILE__)`. I already addressed the *cwd* issue in the latter half of my answer, but there are other ways to skin the cat if you don't want to rely on the value of `Dir.pwd`. YMMV.

Comment: Ok. Then it's even stranger it fails with `shotgun` since it should auto-locate `:root` to the correct folder every time. Strange...