# Sinatra cannot find views directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, runtime-error

I'm trying to structure my Sinatra app in a way that's more similar to the normal Ruby Gem structure. I have the following file tree:

```
.
├── app.rb
├── config.ru
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── helpers
│   ├── dbconfig.rb
│   ├── functions.rb
│   └── init.rb
├── hidden
│   └── Rakefile
├── lib
│   ├── admin.rb
│   ├── api.rb
│   ├── indexer.rb
│   ├── init.rb
│   └── magnet.rb
├── models
│   ├── init.rb
│   ├── invite.rb
│   ├── tag.rb
│   ├── torrent.rb
│   └── user.rb
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── reset.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── i
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── bg.jpg
│   │   ├── dl-icon.png
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   ├── logo-public.png
│   │   ├── magnet-icon.png
│   │   ├── text-logo.png
│   │   ├── text-logo-public.png
│   │   └── upload-icon.png
│   └── js
│       ├── main.js
│       └── torrents.js
├── README.md
├── SPEC.md
├── tmp
│   └── restart.txt
├── TODO.md
└── views
    ├── error.erb
    ├── footer.erb
    ├── header.erb
    ├── index.erb
    ├── list.erb
    ├── nav.erb
    ├── text.erb
    └── upload.erb
```

I have the app files that are trying to render things in `lib/`, but upon (re)starting the Passenger server I get: `Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - /home/dev/indexer/lib/views/index.erb`

The offending few lines are:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366687/why-would-i-get-errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-when-viewing-a-sinatr

Comment: @CodeGnome doesn't work, and not very relevant

Comment: As an aside, most Sinatra projects I've seen tend to put all application specific code in an `app` dir under the project root, so in your case `views`, `public`, `models` and `helpers` would be under the `app` dir. `lib` remains under project root. And all the app code you have in the `lib` dir would be in `app`. Applications aren't libraries, hence the difference in layout.

Comment: @iain, alright that makes sense, but it seems to me that Sinatra is looking in `lib/views` because the core code is in `lib`

Answer (score 6):

Without looking at the content of `rb` files it would be difficult to guess what is wrong. If you routes are defined in `rb` files in sub-folder within root of your application, you would have to explicitly set `views` folder.

In your case, assuming `/app.rb` is the file setting up the basic configuration, you would have to set `views` (or anything else like public folder) in there.

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/views'
  set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/public'
end
```

Else Sinatra would look in to subsequent sub-folders for relevant paths. Further, subsequent route files should extend same class. In this case MyApp. For example, in `./lib/admin.rb`

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/blah" do
    "blah blah"
  end
end
```

Comment: If you've subclassed in the first file required you don't need to express the subclass in the subsequently required files.

Comment: Hmmm... Would this work if I have `Brightswipe::Main` and `Brightswipe::API` and so on? Or should I have this bit of code in each of those?

Answer (score 5):

Specify path to views directory in your configuration block:

```
set :views, "#{settings.root}/../views"
```

See http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__view_template_directory

Comment: I have https://gist.github.com/4584262 in my `app.rb` (not alone), and various modules (I think?) of the `Brightswipe` class in the `models` folder, like `Brightswipe::Main` and `Brightswipe::API`, etc. I just put the statements in my `app.rb` - and it fails with the same error.

Comment: From [the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Views%20/%20Templates) "Templates are assumed to be located directly under the ./views directory." You shouldn't have to specify this option, but if you do, then it should be `set :views, "./views"`, and I'd suggest that either way you do `set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: @iain, I set the root and views folder from `app.rb`, which is in the project root - but to no avail. Since I don't just have the same class `Brightswipe` throughout (I use `Brightswipe::Main`, `Brightswipe::API`, etc), will that make a difference?

Comment: This fix my issue, but why? using ruby app.rb works fine, but unicorn showed the error. When added this it works

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found out what was wrong! All I needed to do was make my classes in the `lib/` folder inherit from the main `Brightswipe` class, which inherited from `Sinatra::Base`.

Comment: N that's exactly whats been said in above answer.